# Making Nutella flow Smoothly

Tags: chocolate

I need a little liquidy version of Nutella for a recipe, how can I achieve this?

I tried blending Nutella with milk but its a messy procedure, is there a clean way to make Nutella more liquidy?

Comment: Just melt it...?

Comment: @Aaronut, how? double boiler?

Answer (score 4):

If it's okay for it to be warm, just heat it a bit in the microwave. (You could also use a double boiler, or even just carefully use a pot, but it's extra effort.)

If you don't want it to be hot, you probably want to try to incrementally mix in some other ingredient from the recipe. If you do it all at once it's difficult to get it mixed evenly, but if you add a bit at a time, it'll slowly thin and you can keep mixing well.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that the Nutella will stand out as an ingredient in your recipe (filling/topping) then a bit of warmed coconut oil or other fat will blend in more easily than other liquids.

At my first bakery, our home-made version was warmed merely by touch, in a mixing bowl, to pouring consistency: a kilo took 20min in winter. Messy but reliably consistent.

Comment: Do you have a recipe for this home-made version? :)